# SQL create view with true/false column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a True/False column in a view. I tried below but it creates a column that is a string instead of BIT.

```
SELECT table.*, 'TRUE' As col
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

Just cast your desired value as a `bit`.

```
SELECT table.*, CAST(1 AS bit) AS col
FROM table

-- or

SELECT table.*, CAST('true' AS bit) AS col
FROM table
```